# How to continuously extract video frames from streaming RTMP using avconv / ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, video-encoding, avconv

We're dealing with streaming video on RTMP and my goal is to extract frames from the stream at a given interval, e.g. every 1 second.

Currently I run a command in a loop, which takes a frame and exports it as base64 JPEG:

```
avconv -i <URL> -y -f image2 -ss 3 -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -s sqcif /dev/stdout 2>/dev/null | base64 -w 0
```

But each of these processes is long (takes a few seconds -- which adds even more delay on streaming video that's not real time already). I am wondering if there is a way to make avconv  or ffmpeg to extract frames at an interval (in seconds or frames) and either save as a file or dump to stdout.

I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: Do you want the extracted image output to be continuously overwritten or do you want numbered, sequential image outputs?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I expect it to be stringified to base64 inline PNG and immediately sent to another server.

Answer (score 3):

did you try this?

```
ffmpeg -i <URL> -r 1 out%03d.jpg
```

Comment: I believe it is adequate as an answer. The example will output 1 frame per second as numerically sequential image files.